# How convert javascript local variable to global veriable?

Tags: javascript

How I convert local variable to global variable in JavaScript?

like

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {

    var fakeRadioButtonsFranType = document.querySelectorAll(".iCheck-helper");
    for (var i = 0; i < fakeRadioButtonsFranType.length; i++) {
        fakeRadioButtonsFranType[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            fran_type = Number(this.parentNode.querySelector("input").value);

            var dataPass = 'fran_type=' + fran_type;
                $.ajax({ // Send the username val to available.php
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataPass,
                    url: '<?= site_url('Alluser/getLocations'); ?>',
                    success: function (responseText) { // Get the result

                       var allZonals = responseText;
                    }
                });
         });
      }
});
```

I want use allZonals variable .

Comment: declare into window object.

Comment: `window.allZonals = allZonals`. Or don't declare it as a `var` but just use `window.allZonals `

Comment: assign to window object or create in global scope, and just modify

Comment: As I understand your problem you want to access response outside ajax.

Comment: Hint: your other variable `fran_type` is already global...

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it to global `window` object:

```
window.allZonals = responseText;
```